# Best kit to boom wireless

Tags: wireless, booming

Hi,

I did originally ask what wireless kits you guys considered to be the best and I got some great responses, thanks. The lectro and Zaxcom lines look great. But I forgot to add in that I am looking at a transmitter/receiver combo for multi wireless booming on a reality TV series. Would you guys recommend the same sources or are there alternate options that I must consider.

Thank.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the same in my opinion.

Comment: Second that, but I will give the Sennheiser transmitter pack a word up here. It is a good bit of kit to keep for booms or quick change from cable to wireless. A little heavy, but a good boom operator won't have an issue. I actually like it for hand held mics, say someone wanting to do an "on camera" interview with a mic to hand around. Another good thing about it for the kit back is that you can whack it into an output of a mixing desk or other sound source for another track of audio from set. Just a cheap-ish flexible bit of kit.